# Return a list of a Entity class

Tags: c#, list, ilist

This is my Class:

```
public class Customer
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }

      public string Card_ID { get; set; }

      public double Cash { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public Image Photo { get; set; }
   }
```

I need to make a `SELECT` on my database to get some information of the `customer`, I used to use `DataSet` but I saw it's not the best choice when it comes to performance. Also I need to read only 2 or 3 fields, I started this method:

```
public List<Customer> ConsultCustomerData(string cardID)
   {
      list<Customer> customer = null;
      string sql = "SELECT name, cash FROM customers WHERE card_id = @cardID";            
       try
          {
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cardID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = cardID;

           }
        catch (Exception ex)
          {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
          }
   }
```

Now I don't know how to continue...
How may I return those informations using `List` or `IList` ?

Comment: you may use Entity Framework or any kind of ORM.

Comment: I thought maybe use a `DataReader` then loop through it then assign it's values into the `customer.Field`. But I coudn't make it =\

Comment: For each of the `cmd`'s results, you'll have to parse the data back into a `Customer` object. Or use an ORM like Entity Framework, that does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use command.ExecuteReader method and fill entity data using reader.

```
 public List<Customer> ConsultCustomerData(string cardID)
 {
    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
    string sql = "SELECT name, cash FROM customers WHERE card_id = @cardID";        

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@cardID", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = cardID;

    using (IDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
             list.Add(new Customer { 
                 Name = reader.GetString(0), 
                 Cash = reader.GetDouble(1) 
             });
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Check:

1. ADO.NET [IDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.aspx) interface and its [MySql implementation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html)
2. ADO.NET [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) interface and its [MySql implementation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html)

Comment: Someone said I could easily get a SQL injection, could you save me from that ?

Comment: You already saved yourself from sql injection by using parameters.

Comment: That's what I tought... Thanks

Comment: If I don't use something like = `list.Name = reader["name"].ToString()` . How do the reader now wich value pass to the `list.Name` ?

Comment: You give the column ordinal from your select statement. It is zero-based

Comment: I tried to receive the returned list, but I got error of convesion.    
`List<Customer> customer = ConsultCustomerData(cardID);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a detareader with your query. Afer initialize youe list. The do 
`while(datareader.read())` and inside your loop create a Customer object giving reader's values and at the end add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the good 'ol fashioned way with `cmd.ExecuteReader()` or use a nice ORM like [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).

```
public List<Customer> ConsultCustomerData(string cardID)
{
    const string query = "SELECT name, cash FROM customers WHERE card_id = @cardID";
    try
    {
        using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.Query<Customer>(query, new { cardID }).ToList();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging, etc..
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        throw; //Rethrow exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used ORM. Would you have a good article about it ? I'll read about it

Comment: Google and StackOverflow have some pretty good articles for ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely push for switching to using an ORM like Entity Framework or even Linq to SQL - However, to answer your question you need to *read* the information from the query i.e.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        customers.Add(new Customer
        {
            Name = reader.GetString(0),
            Cash = reader.GetDouble(1)
        });
    }
    return customers;
}
```

Comment: i've never used `Entity Framework` is it so hard ? I'll read about it now.

Comment: @Ghaleon not really, over the years it's been simplified - you should probably look at the [code first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj200620) approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Data Reader for reading the data and set associated data to to your entity and build the list like shown as below.

```
    list <Customer> lstCustomer =new list <Customer>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         Customer cus=new Customer();
         cus.Card_ID =......
            .............
            ................
            lstCustomer.Add(cus);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Model.edmx to your project. Then you can easily understand the rest. It creates the model for you. You don't need to worry about creating classes. Also helpful if you have table relationship. You don't have to write SQL code to write or read from database.

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) how to use EF.

Comment: I'm watching the video of your link. What's the difference between this Entity Framework and a Typed Dataset?

Comment: @Ghaleon you may find the answer from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx